# Symfony2: map every request parameter to object with type mapping and validation

Tags: php, symfony, request, datamapper, data-mapping

In our current application we have plenty of classes what represents acceptable request inputs. All of them extends abstract types like String, Integer etc.
There are some advantages of our implementation:

- We can automatically validate input data (HTTP 400: Param xx must be an integer gt 0)
- We can add custom validation (HTTP 400: Invalid postcode)
- In every controller we don't need to care about request parameters data types

So now, we planning migrate to Symfony2. And we cannot see solution to do it in this framework, or even better way to accomplish that.

Is there a way to map every request param to pre-configured data type? We only use simple types (int, string, bool etc)

Or maybe our solution is not quite good? We can't see any disadvantages except many classes (maybe we should configure them in some xml/yml)